# Displaying tabular data using columnar with python

Tags: python, json, django

I have the structure as follows. I show it as a table with the columnar library. It works just fine. But because the incoming json data is "dict", it does not show it as a single line.

How can I show the above json data in single print (table) print screen?

[image: It does not show the incoming data in a single row, it creates a new table and displays it separately. I want it to show in a single table]

```
    from time import sleep
    from django.views.decorators.http import require_POST
    import json
    from django.http import HttpResponse
    from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
    import django_filters.rest_framework
    import requests
    from columnar import columnar
    from tabulate import tabulate
    
    
    
    @require_POST
    @csrf_exempt
    def webhook(request):
    
        while True:
            get_active_position()
    
    
        return HttpResponse(request, content_type='application/json')
    
    
    
    def get_active_position():
        print("get_active position")
    
        data = "{'symbol': 'BCHUSDT', 'positionAmt': '0.001', 'entryPrice': '266.85000', 'markPrice': '259.99000000', 'unRealizedProfit': '-0.00686000', 'liquidationPrice': '0', 'leverage': '20', 'maxNotionalValue': '250000', 'marginType': 'cross', 'isolatedMargin': '0.00000000', 'isAutoAddMargin': 'false', 'positionSide': 'LONG'}
    {'symbol': 'ETHUSDT', 'positionAmt': '0.001', 'entryPrice': '385.88000', 'markPrice': '381.85854735', 'unRealizedProfit': '-0.00402145', 'liquidationPrice': '0', 'leverage': '10', 'maxNotionalValue': '2000000', 'marginType': 'cross', 'isolatedMargin': '0.00000000', 'isAutoAddMargin': 'false', 'positionSide': 'LONG'}
    "
        for sym in data:
            if sym['positionAmt'][:1] == "-" and sym['positionAmt'] <= str("0.00000"):
                headers = ["Symbol", "EntryPrice", "positionSize", "Side"]
                symbols = [
                    [sym['symbol'], sym['entrypPrice']]
                ]
                table = columnar(symbols, headers=headers)
                print(table)
    
    
            # Long position
            elif sym['positionAmt'] >= str("0.00000"):
                headers = ["Symbol", "EntryPrice", "positionSize", "Side"]
                symbols = [
                    [sym['symbol'], sym['entrypPrice']]
                ]
                table = columnar(symbols, headers=headers)
                print(table)
    
        return get_active_position
```

Comment: If you use a view rendering a Django template, then you have to design your template on a way that will have this structure, otherwise you can use Pandas to process tabular data.

Comment: Yes I am using django but json data comes from binance.com.
It shows in a table according to the incoming data, but opens a new table for each row.